# BMW E90 330d door lock fault

Tags: bmw, fob, central-locking

Using BMW key fob door unlocks saloon vehicle, internal dash mount button opens and locks all doors. However, keyfob remote will not lock the car. I have checked the fuses and relays and they are all ok. What could it be?

Comment: How have you checked the relays? E90s are notorious for this and it is usually a relay in the passenger compartment. Either that or a faulty footwell module or button in the key fob.

Comment: What does "saloon" (in your first sentence) mean?